# Subscript square

Tags: subscripts, size, amsfonts

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\varphi_\square$
\end{document}
```

Output doesn't look right. The square is too big and doesn't look like a subscript at all. Is there a way to make the square smaller and/or lower?

Comment: This is exactly the right way to type it. The fact is that `varphi` is not a tall symbol and it has a depth. Compare with `$\varphi_\square \alpha_\square f_\square$`.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
$\varphi_{\square}$

$\varphi_{\scriptscriptstyle\square}$


\end{document}
```

other fonts have more choices

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
$\varphi_{\mdlgwhtsquare}$

$\varphi_{\smwhtsquare}$

$\varphi_{\mdwhtsquare}$

$\varphi_{\lgwhtsquare}$

$\varphi_{\vysmwhtsquare}$


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe one of these is more like you want?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsfonts, stmaryrd}

    \begin{document}

     $\varphi_{{}_\square}$ \qquad $\varphi_{{}_\boxempty}$ \qquad $\varphi_{{}_\oblong}$

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `\square` from `amssymb` is quite large. You can lower it by adding an empty superscript.

Or you can borrow the smaller square from `mathabx`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%% borrow \square from mathabx, but calling it \smallsquare
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-8.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\smallsquare}{\mathord}{mathb}{"05}
%%%

\begin{document}

$\varphi_{\square}\square$

$\varphi^{}_{\square}\square$

$\varphi_{\smallsquare}\smallsquare$

$\varphi^{}_{\smallsquare}\smallsquare$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can make the square any size you want with `\scalebox`. Here it is turned into a macro called `\smsq`. I set the default scaling factor to `.5` but you can change that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,graphicx}
\newcommand{\smsq}[1][.5]{\scalebox{#1}{$\square$}}

\begin{document}
$\varphi_\square\quad\varphi_{\smsq}\quad\varphi_{\smsq[.3]}$
\end{document}
```